# How to put data in fields when updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui

Here is the scenario:

I want to use the same form to create a product and update a product.
The form is made with components of Material UI (TextFields).

My product creation form works (unless no image is put).
To update, I manage to return the information to my form, but I don't know how to put its data in my fields (Probably with value but I have errors (null or undefined).

Here is the head of my form (Creation and modification) :

[image]

(Same form, only the title change (Modification of a Product)

[image]

Here is the link to send the product information to be modified to my form page :

```
<Link to={`/produit/${produit.id}`}>
```

The axios request made by getProduitById(id) :

```
export const getProduitById = (id) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/produit/:id`.replace(':id', id));
```

And finally, the code of how I get the product information :

```
 useEffect(() => {
        getMarque()

        if (id) {
            getProduitById(id).then(response => {
                if (response.data){
                    console.log(response.data.marqueId)
                    setProduit({
                        nom: response.data.nom,
                        prix: response.data.prix,
                        description: response.data.description,
                        qtestock: response.data.qtestock,
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }, [])
```

And that's it. I try to ensure that, when I arrive on the form following my modification Link, the fields are filled with the previous information of the product

(And a little screen to show you that I get the product information in my console :)
[image]

Comment: Setting `produit` values in your `TextField`s after the request using the `value` attribute should work for your case. Could you also add the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't know why but I don't have a error anymore after some checking and reloading...
But value work but it's impossible to change the text of the field and defaultValue seems to not working at all

Comment: Using the value attribute makes the TextField controlled. So an onChange handler function is also required to change the contents of the TextField.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, this is what I read online. If I use a value, an onChange is required to be able to change the text inside my TextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem with 'value' and a function 'onChange'
For anyone, here's the code :

Form :

```
<TextField style={TextFieldStyle} value={produit.nom} id='nom' name='nom' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Entrez le nom du produit' type='string' fullWidth required variant='outlined' />
```

How I got my product information :

```
useEffect(() => {

        if (id) {
            getProduitById(id).then(response => {
                if (response.data){
                    console.log(response.data)
                    setProduit({
                        nom: response.data.nom,
                        prix: response.data.prix,
                        description: response.data.description,
                        imageurl: response.data.imageurl,
                        qtestock: response.data.qtestock,
                        marqueId: response.data.marqueId,
                    })
                    console.log(produit)
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }, [])
```

onChange :

```
const [produit, setProduit] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setProduit({ 
        ...produit,
        [e.target.name]: value });
}
```